How to use the Teamcenter SOA to get optimized or formatted classification attribute values of a classification object?
I am using the Teamcenter SOA ClassificationService.getClassificationObjectInfo operation to get the attribute values and attribute descriptions of a classification object and its class. This works well so far. However, the retrieved attribute values appear unformatted / not optimized even though I am setting getOptimizedValues to true. The attributes still appear as 03.5 instead of 3.5. The documentation states that using getOptimizedValues=true will strip the leading zeros.
Other operations of the ClassificationService also return the attribute values as unformatted / not optimized.
I also tried setting formatProperties=true using the SessionService.setUserSessionState operation directly after login, but this also did not help.
How can I retrieve optimized/formatted classification attribute values?
